# i couldn't fix the problem createview is missing a queryset

Tags: python, django

**ImproperlyConfigured at /register/
SignUpView is missing a QuerySet. Define SignUpView.model, SignUpView.queryset, or override SignUpView.get_queryset().
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/register/
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:

SignUpView is missing a QuerySet. Define SignUpView.model, SignUpView.queryset, or override SignUpView.get_queryset().
Exception Location: D:\ch\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py in get_queryset, line 69
Python Executable:  D:\ch\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3
Python Path:

['D:\ch\ch',
 'D:\ch\env\Scripts\python38.zip',
 'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\DLLs',
 'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib',
 'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38',
 'D:\ch\env',
 'D:\ch\env\lib\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 12 Jun 2020 15:12:00 +0000**

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, CreateView
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'common/home.html'
class DashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView):
    template_name = 'common/home.html'
    login_url = reverse_lazy('home')
class SignUpView(CreateView):
    from_class = SignUpForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'common/register.html'
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path
from apps.common.views import HomeView, SignUpView, DashboardView
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('register/', SignUpView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(
        template_name='common/login.html'
    ),
    name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(
        next_page='home'
    ),
    name='logout'),
    path('dashboard/', DashboardView.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
]
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Enter a valid email address')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username', 
            'first_name', 
            'last_name', 
            'email', 
            'password1', 
            'password2', 
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `model` attribute (or the `queryset` or `get_queryset`) of the `CreateView`:

```
class SignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    from_class = SignUpForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'common/register.html'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the spelling of the information after class instantiation.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic

class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'
```

I made the mistake of spelling "form_class" as "from_class".

Answer (score 0):

Form is wrongly spelt in the SignUpView class.Fix it and it should work fine.